# Evaluate $\int\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{\sin(2x)+2}} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to solve this integral:
$$
\int\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{\sin(2x)+2}} \, dx
$$

In order to solve it, I think that the right technique to use is integration by substitution. Firstly I have converted $\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ and after that I have changed  $\cos(x) = 1 - \sin(x)^2$ and I have replaced $\sin(x) = t$ and the integral becomes
$$
\int\dfrac{t}{1+t-t^3} \, dt
$$
How should I continue?

Comment: $\cos x \neq 1-\sin^2x$

Comment: Would you mind explicitly writing out your steps? Even after taking @Ankit's observation into account, your final result is 'unexpected'... It would be more important for you/us to see how you got there than how to solve the problem - though you might not believe it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $x=t+\frac\pi4$. Then

$$
\int\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{\sin 2x+2}} \, dx
= \frac1{\sqrt2}\int \frac{\sin t}{\sqrt{1+2\cos^2 t}}dt
 + \frac1{\sqrt2}\int \frac{\cos t}{\sqrt{3-2\sin^2 t}}dt\\
\hspace{10mm}=-\frac12\sinh^{-1}\sqrt2 \cos t +\frac12\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\frac23}\sin t+C
$$

Comment: how did you get sinh^-1 and sin^-1 ?

Comment: @Badro - sub $y=\sqrt2\cos t$ in the 1st integral and apply $(\sinh^{-1}y )’= \frac1{\sqrt{1+y^2}}$; similarly for the 2nd integral.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

As $(\sin x+\cos x)^2=?, (\sin x-\cos x)^2=?$

and $\displaystyle\int(\sin x-\cos x)dx=-(\cos x+\sin x)$

and $\displaystyle\int(\sin x+\cos x)dx=?,$

Use

$$\dfrac{2\sin x}{\sqrt{2+\sin2x}}=\dfrac{\sin x-\cos x}{\sqrt{(\sin x+\cos x)^2+1}}+\dfrac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sqrt{3-(\sin x-\cos x)^2}}$$

Comment: I am sorry i didn't get

Comment: @Badro, For the first integral, set $\sin x+\cos x=u$

Comment: what about the denominator ? is it possible that i get the full answer ?

Comment: @Badro, What do you get if you substitute in the first integral $$\sin x+\cos x=u$$  and  for the second, $$\sin x-\cos x=v$$

Answer (score 1):

Use $\sin(2x) = 2\cos^2(x)-1$

The denominator becomes $\sqrt{\sin(2x)+2} = \sqrt{1 + 2\cos^2(x)}$.

Now substitute $\cos(x) = t$ and the integral turns into $\int -\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+2t^2}}$.

Finally, substitute $t = \tan(u)/\sqrt{2}$, $\tan^2(u)+1 = \sec^2(u)$, and $\sqrt{2} dt = \sec^2(u)du$ to change the integral to a standard problem: $-\int \sec(u) du = -\ln \left( \sec(u) + \tan(u) \right) + C$.

Comment: the formula you give is for $cos(2x)$, not $sin(2x)$. However if you first make the substitution $u=\pi/4-x$ to turn the sine in the denominator into a cosine, then I think your suggestion will work.

Comment: You are right. Thanks @Carmeister

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a few hints to work this out. Firstly, note that $2+\sin(2x)=1+(1+2\sin x\cos x)$
Now, $$(1+2\sin x \cos x)=(\sin x + \cos x)^2...(1)$$
$$=2-(\cos x -\sin x)^2...(2)$$
Now, write the numerator as $\sin x=\frac 12((\sin x + \cos x)+ (\sin x- \cos x))$ and separate into two integrals. Now observe that:
$$\frac {d(\sin x+\cos x)}{dx}=\cos x -\sin x$$ and
$$\frac {d(\sin x-\cos x)}{dx}=\cos x+\sin x$$
Can you finish now?

Comment: I am sorry i didn't get